# How Would a CPU Improve if its Logic Circuits were Reduced?

Tags: digital-logic, cpu, theory, boolean-algebra

Is there an estimate as to how a common CPU (for example, Intel i7) would improve if all of its logic circuits were reduced  to their theoretical minimum, in the sense explained [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circuit_minimization_for_Boolean_functions)? By "improve" I mean in metrics such as: size, number of transistors, power consumption, speed.

Comment: What makes you think it isn't done already? Intel isn't a bunch of noobs.

Comment: It is pretty close to the (todays) reachable minimum.

Comment: Interesting article that looks at this sort of thing: http://www.theregister.co.uk/2016/06/01/arm_cortex_a73/

Comment: @PlasmaHH Well, one might claim, that most of the logic is synthesized using NANDs, and it can be improved by using other types of logic...

Comment: @EugeneSh.: yeah, I also might claim that it is hand written by 1st sememster liberal arts students

Comment: @EugeneSh. Yes, one of the most advanced semiconductor companies in the world is using NAND synthesis to make processors. /s

Comment: @PlasmaHH I assumed that since the problem is computationally very hard, it is probably far from being close to the minimum.

Comment: @BrendanSimpson It's not like they are taking gates and connecting them manually. But it is the technology, you know...

Comment: @EugeneSh. I can virtually guarantee that at least some decent percentage of an Intel processor is manually placed and routed, but even beyond that, modern EDA tools are well beyond NAND implementations. Why would an optimizing compiler pick 4 transistors for an inverter when only two are needed?

Comment: @EugeneSh.: Intels expertise is not at actually laying out a CPU, its expertise is at writing an inhouse software that lays out a CPU.

Comment: Intels expertise is at manufacturing chips, improving the tech behind chip production, not at designing what goes into their personal chips that they build.

Comment: you cant improve all of size, speed, cost, number of transistors, some of those are inversely related, reducing some you increase others.  remove your speed requirement for example and you can reduce cost, power and number of transistors.

Comment: Oh, the flames...  Place and route tools are terrible with colored metals.  Here's a question where I showed the layout of a colored XOR finFET at 14nm actual: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/14688/how-can-cpus-be-stable-when-they-have-so-many-transistors/220093#220093  Routers do a terrible job with complex gates and colored metal, and often we end up with forced symmetry, so placing arbitrary logic gates is difficult with multiple grids for fins/poly/metal.  You don't have to take my word for it: https://www.iarpa.gov/index.php/research-programs/supertools

Comment: look at a simple multiply, you want it in one clock it takes a relatively massive number of gates.  want to do it in many clocks, super easy, trivial number of gates.

Comment: @dwelch PlasmaHH is on the spot! Whilst Intel is the dominant process company on the planet they also have internal tools for the design of their processors. On their core processors they don't use an ASIC flow but use structures that are latch based with complimentary non over lapped clocks for skew minimization. And they write their own software. they use synthesis for the chips like the northbridge and smaller processors but the i7's use the custom tools. I know this from reading papers and attending conferences as well as having friends in that software group.

Comment: right they make impressive designs that tune for speed. are well known for their excessive power consumption.  most of their market is going away, it is trivial to beat them when it comes to mips to mhz, they see the handwriting on the wall and are opening their foundries to outsiders as a way of staying in business. if their tools were so great they would be able to bang out a phone or tablet processor rather than just grossly underclock an old design.  as mentioned, you cant have all of those features, in their case sacrifice power for basically the server market as that is all that is left

Comment: that and contract manufacture which they can beat tsmc in some respects.  and certainly push the technology smaller.

Comment: Former Intel employee here, worked in high-speed digital design and serial-IO.  Can guarantee you it is not just NAND gates, but are heavily optimized outputs using latest in-house or commercial synthesis (EDA) software.  Structured datapath often still done by hand, at least on the critical timing paths. @dwelch There is much more to entering a new market than "bang out a phone or tablet processor" but if you'd like to know more you can read the tomes that have been written on the subject in various industry magazines.

Comment: i am in the industry as well with many former intel employees...

Answer (score 8):

I worked for a decade at a startup doing computerised logic improvement for chip designers; we were eventually bought by Cadence.

We had, among a whole bunch of other tools, a heuristic logic minimiser. It was a fairly simple thing that just pushed "bubbles" (negations) around, and attempted to absorb gates into the slightly more efficient AOI or OAI composite gates. It would then compute a cost function to see if this was a good idea.

What turned out to be far more critical was logic *duplication*. It seems counterintuitive to add more gates computing the same logic function, but the important thing in ASIC performance is the *critical path*. The logic path that takes longest to compute determines the speed of the whole chip. Adding additional outputs from a gate slows it down, especially if those outputs are to far-away locations. You could get a noticeable improvement by having two copies of logic to compute f(A,B,C) where one was "fast" and close to where it was needed and another "slow" one to a less-critical destination.

The extreme of this is buffering. A naive logic removal function would take out all your buffers - after all, they're just the identity function - which would save you a lot of area but ruin the speed.

Optimal logic *placement* is, I think, also NP-complete. It's very similar to subset-sum. Again, this is one of those problems which is easiest to solve in practice by pretending it's linear, throwing it at an LP-solver, and having other bits of program go round tidying up the nonlinearity.

Comment: An additional problem is that even in optimizing for performance one must consider power costs. Yield, i.e., the effect of process variation on the design, must also be considered; a design that provides 20% greater performance for 5% of chips but 50% less .for 90% of chips would typically not be economically practical. (Time to market also limits how much optimization can be done.)

Answer (score 4):

The CPU chips that you can buy (for example, Intel i7) are optimized for the maximum speed and lowest power available at the current level of high-volume manufacturing process technology. To be sure they are always working on the feature set, circuit design, device technology, and the manufacturing processes that will help make the next generations of CPU chips even faster and lower power.

Theoretical gates in a college text are quite a different thing from integrating literally billions of transistors on a chip the size of your thumb-nail. The actual transistor-level circuit that goes into a gate is quite different if you compare a simple 7400 quad NAND gate small-scale integration vs. a modern high-end CPU chip.

And approaching the clock-speed limit in traditional Silicon-based semiconductor chips means that increasing performance has shifted to using parallel processing vs. sheer linear-path speed. But there may be other elements that offer speeds beyond what we can get out of silicon.